# Is there a way to update the number of concurrency in ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I developing an application which using the spring-kafka package and changing the amount of data it handled in run time.  
I want to let the system the ability to change in run time the number of `concurrency` depend on the pressure the system feel (something that I will defined). 
Right now the my solution is to `doStop` and `doStart` the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` explicitly but I look for a clean way which not damage the stream and not touch an internal methods of the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to interact with these internal methods; use `stop()` and `start()`, which are public, instead.

You cannot change the concurrency dynamically, only by stopping and starting the container, changing the concurrency while stopped.